# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'?

Tags: k-fold

"this is a code, folds are created but problem is with fit function"
"this is a code, folds are created but problem is with fit function"
"this is a code, folds are created but problem is with fit function"

```
data = pd.read_csv('Augsynonym.csv')
print(data)
txt= data['Text']
sent = data['Sentiment']
kf =KFold(n_splits=5)
model = LogisticRegression(solver= 'liblinear')
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
acc_score = []
Xtrain=[]
xtest=[]
for train_set, test_set in kf.split(txt):
    print(train_set, len(train_set))
    print(test_set, len(test_set))
    X_train , X_test = txt.iloc[train_set],txt.iloc[test_set]
    y_train , y_test = sent[train_set] , sent[test_set]
    Xtrain.append(X_train)
    xtest.append(X_test)
xtrain = vectorizer.fit_transform(Xtrain)`enter code here`
testx = vectorizer.fit_transform(xtest)
model.fit(xtrain,y_train)
pred_values = model.predict(testx)
acc = accuracy_score(pred_values , y_test)
acc_score.append(acc)
```